# Как получить доступ к серверу на хостинге из браузера, программы, приложения на телефоне?

Tags: python, framework

Очень интересный способы подключения к серверу и сбора от туда данных.

- Как подключиться к серверу разными способами с разных устройств?
- Как обрабатывать разные подключения с разных устройств?

В первую очередь интересен python, для написания клиента и сервера.

На данный момент слышал про rest api.
Знаю сокеты и как пользоваться.

Comment: Если что-то не так с вопросом, переделаю.

Comment: А в чём проблема? Любое устройство, поддерживающее нужные протоколы, может подключится к серверу. Как по `SSH`, `FTP`, так и по `HTTP`. В случае с `HTTP`, Вы можете фильтровать запросы по заголовку `User-Agent` или использовать `JavaScript` на стороне клиента.